# WatchDog Library is only running once

Tags: python, tkinter, python-watchdog

I am new to coding and python, and I am struggling to use this WatchDog library to run this data_analysis function when a file is added to a folder. While it runs, i notice that pasting this function makes the watchdog only detect an added file once. Without, it will keep running. Anyone know why? I have tried searching online but I am endlessly confused lol Also, I tried to pasting my whole function to make it easier to read, but if you can condense it in your IDE, then it should be easier to see the rest of the py file.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Watchdog(PatternMatchingEventHandler, Observer):
    def __init__(self, path='.', patterns='*', logfunc=print):
        PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns)
        Observer.__init__(self)
        self.schedule(self, path=path, recursive=False)
        self.log = logfunc

    def on_created(self, event):
        # This function is called when a file is created
        self.log(f"hey, {event.src_path} has been created!")
        def data_analysis(src_path):
            readdata = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, delimiter='\t', encoding="latin1", skiprows=24)
            df = pd.DataFrame(readdata)
    
            df = df.drop(labels=0, axis=0)
            
            df['Station']=df['Station'].astype(float)
            df['Station']=df['Station'].astype(int)
    
            df["Axial Force Occurences"] = 0
            df["Axial Force Actual Value"] = pd.NaT
    
            df["Flexion Occurences"] = 0
            df["Flexion Actual Value"] = pd.NaT
    
            df["IE Occurences"] = 0
            df["IE Actual Value"] = pd.NaT
    
            df["AP Occurences"] = 0
            df["AP Actual Value"] = pd.NaT
    
            df['Fz 1']=df['Fz 1'].astype(float)
            df['Fz 1']=df['Fz 1'].astype(int)
    
            df['VLWf']=df['VLWf'].astype(float)
            df['VLWf']=df['VLWf'].astype(int)
    
            df['FLPt']=df['FLPt'].astype(float)
            # df['FLPt']=df['FLPt'].astype(int)
    
            df['FLWf']=df['FLWf'].astype(float)
            # df['FLWf']=df['FLWf'].astype(int)
    
            df['IEPt']=df['IEPt'].astype(float)
            # df['IEPt']=df['IEPt'].astype(int)
    
            df['IEWf']=df['IEWf'].astype(float)
            # df['IEWf']=df['IEWf'].astype(int)
    
            df['APPt']=df['APPt'].astype(float)
            # df['APPt']=df['APPt'].astype(int)
    
            df['APWf']=df['APWf'].astype(float)
            # df['APWf']=df['APWf'].astype(int)
    
    
            data = df.loc[df['Station'] == 1, ['VLWf','Fz 1', "Axial Force Occurences", "Axial Force Actual Value",
                                                'FLPt', 'FLWf', "Flexion Occurences", "Flexion Actual Value", 
                                                'IEPt', 'IEWf', "IE Occurences", "IE Actual Value", 
                                                'APPt', 'APWf', "AP Occurences", "AP Actual Value", ]]
    
            tol = 3
            y = int(len(data.index))
    
            num = int(y * (3/100))
    
            ##Extract first and last rows based on tolerance, and append the first rows to the end, and the last rows to the beginning
            first_rows = data.iloc[0: num]
            last_rows = data.iloc[y-num: y]
    
            ##Add the last_rows to the beginning, and the first_rows to the end, all one df
            data = last_rows.append(data)
            data = data.append(first_rows)
            ##This keeps the indexing from appending, which is nice to see, but we need to change it use for loops
            z = int(len(data.index))
            new_index = np.linspace(start = 1, stop = z, num = z)
            new_index2 = new_index.astype(int)
            data2 = data.set_index(new_index2)
    
            # To test if the tables are correct, you can call specific values in console eg: 'data['VLWf'].iloc[1]'
            axoccur = []
            ##AXIAL FORCE OOT
            for i in range(num, z-num): 
                val = data2['Fz 1'].iloc[i]
                extract_data = data2.iloc[1:z, 0]
                xval = data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,0]-0.5*2600
                
                if np.any(val >= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,0])-0.05*2600)) and np.any(val <= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,0])+0.05*2600)):
                    data2.at[i,'Axial Force Occurences'] = 0
    
                else:
                    data2.at[i,'Axial Force Occurences'] = 1
                    data2.at[i,'Axial Force Actual Value'] = val
                    axoccur.append(i)
                    # print(apoccur)
                    
            ##After reading the data, we need to sum the 
            totalaxial = data2['Axial Force Occurences'].sum()
            print('The number of Axial Force values outside of the tolerance is: ' + str(totalaxial))
    
            flexionoccur = []
            ##FLEXION OOT
            for i in range(num, z-num): 
                val = data2['FLPt'].iloc[i]
                extract_data = data2.iloc[1:z, 0]
                xval = data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,0]-0.5*2600
                
                if np.any(val >= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,5])-0.05*58)) and np.any(val <= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,5])+0.05*58)):
                    data2.at[i,'Flexion Occurences'] = 0
    
                else:
                    data2.at[i,'Flexion Occurences'] = 1
                    data2.at[i,'Flexion Actual Value'] = val
                    flexionoccur.append(i)
    
            ##After reading the data, we need to sum the 
            totalflexion = data2['Flexion Occurences'].sum()
            print('The number of Flexion values outside of the tolerance is: ' + str(totalflexion))
    
            ieoccur = []
            ##IE OOT
            for i in range(num, z-num): 
                val = data2['IEPt'].iloc[i]
                extract_data = data2.iloc[1:z, 0]
                xval = data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,0]-0.5*2600
                
                if np.any(val >= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,9])-0.05*5.7)) and np.any(val <= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,9])+0.05*5.7)):
                    data2.at[i,'IE Occurences'] = 0
    
                else:
                    data2.at[i,'IE Occurences'] = 1
                    data2.at[i,'IE Actual Value'] = val
                    ieoccur.append(i)
                    
            ##After reading the data, we need to sum the 
            totalie = data2['IE Occurences'].sum()
            print('The number of IE values outside of the tolerance is: ' + str(totalie))
    
            apoccur = []
            ##AP OOT
            for i in range(num, z-num): 
                val = data2['APPt'].iloc[i]
                extract_data = data2.iloc[1:z, 0]
                xval = data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,0]-0.5*2600
                
                if np.any(val >= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,13])-0.05*5.2)) and np.any(val <= ((data2.iloc[i-num: i+num,13])+0.05*5.2)):
                    data2.at[i,'IE Occurences'] = 0
    
                else:
                    data2.at[i,'AP Occurences'] = 1
                    data2.at[i,'AP Actual Value'] = val  
                    apoccur.append(i)
                    
            ##After reading the data, we need to sum the 
            totalap = data2['AP Occurences'].sum()
            print('The number of AP values outside of the tolerance is: ' + str(totalap))
        data_analysis(event.src_path)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        # This function is called when a file is deleted
        self.log(f"what the f**k! Someone deleted {event.src_path}!")

    def on_modified(self, event):
        # This function is called when a file is modified
        self.log(f"hey buddy, {event.src_path} has been modified")

    def on_moved(self, event):
        # This function is called when a file is moved    
        self.log(f"ok ok ok, someone moved {event.src_path} to {event.dest_path}")

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.watchdog = None
        self.watch_path = '.'
        self.root = Tk()
        self.messagebox = Text(width=80, height=10)
        self.messagebox.pack()
        frm = Frame(self.root)
        Button(frm, text='Browse', command=self.select_path).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(frm, text='Start Watchdog', command=self.start_watchdog).pack(side=RIGHT)
        Button(frm, text='Stop Watchdog', command=self.stop_watchdog).pack(side=RIGHT)
        # Button(frm, text='Excel', command=self.excelexport)pack(side=LEFT)
        frm.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def start_watchdog(self):
        if self.watchdog is None:
            self.watchdog = Watchdog(path=self.watch_path, logfunc=self.log)
            self.watchdog.start()
            self.log('Watchdog started')

        else:
            self.log('Watchdog already started')

    def stop_watchdog(self):
        if self.watchdog:
            self.watchdog.stop()
            self.watchdog = None
            self.log('Watchdog stopped')
        else:
            self.log('Watchdog is not running')

    def select_path(self):
        path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        if path:
            self.watch_path = path
            self.log(f'Selected path: {path}')

    def log(self, message):
        self.messagebox.insert(END, f'{message}\n')
        self.messagebox.see(END)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI()
```

Comment: Do we really need to go all this code through ? Couldn't you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Handler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=['*.pdf'],
                                                           ignore_patterns = None,
                                                           ignore_directories = False,
                                                           case_sensitive = False)
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f"File was created at {event.src_path}")
        OCRscript(self, event)
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print(f"File was deleted at {event.src_path}")

event_handler = Handler()
observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, "C://Users//Installer//Desktop//tesseract test",
                  recursive = False)
observer.start()
observer.join()
```

This is the code I have been using to have a continually running watchdog. I call my other functions from within the class to ensure that the watchdog continues running. I have the functions I'm calling defined outside of the class just for debugging purposes. It helped me figure out which step was broken.